# Why Microsoft Windows boot time is too high?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot

I see in the forums that if we use SSD hard disk the windows boot time will reduce from 50 second to about 10 second.

I didn't know why? I tried to load a 1 GB file with a simple c# program and it need just *832ms*(Edit: 1228ms with random data) with a normal hard disk.

- The problem is *not the processing problem* because with the SSD we can
  have less than 10 seconds to load.
- The problem is *not the hard disk read speed problem* because we can read 1 GB less than *850ms*(Edit:1250 ms)

The problem may because of

- Loading too many files!    **If so, Why Microsoft didn't compact them in
  one file?**
- Too many logging and write process in boot time! **If so, what are
  them?**
- Please tell me.

and How can i resolve them?

Please tell me why get me rate down :(

the code for test hard read speed.

```
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
        var s2 = new Stopwatch();
        s2.Start();
        var f2 = File.OpenRead(@"d:\test.size");
        int size=f2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        f2.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("read time:" + s2.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Comment: There's no way you can load 1GB in less than 1 second on a hard drive since the fastest consumer models max out at about 150MB/s so your code is obviously wrong. But anyway, Windows 8 should start pretty quickly as it uses some new techniques to reduce the number of files it has to read at startup. If this still isn't quick enough for you then I suggest you use the standby or hibernate options instead of shutting down.

Comment: @James I test it again with random data and i'm sure that i read 1GB in 1228ms.
**I wrote 1GB in 18Second but read it in 1228ms**

I have windows 8.1 and it need about 50 second to load. Hibernate got about 40 second in my 8Gb ram laptop.

Comment: The file is probably being cached in memory so is not actually being read from disk.

Comment: If your computer is taking a long time to start up then it it might be bogged down with bloatware/malware, you might have a corrupt Windows installation, you might have faulty hardware, or you might just have a slow computer.

Comment: @James Yes you are right, The Windows has been cached the read data! I make 4 different 1GB file and make cache empty and test speed again. it took about 18second to read. :)
Please add Your idea as the solution.

Comment: @James My computer is not slow and i'm sure my computer has no malware.(fresh windows got about 50 second and no the windows got more time). my laptop is vaio s seri core-i5 with 8GB ram and hard with 60MB/s read speed.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  If you required 50 seconds to load Windows 8.1 then you have huge amount of programs starting at start-up.  My non SSD system only requires half that time to boot.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to load a 1 GB file with a simple c# program and it need just
>   832ms

You can't normally load a 1GB in less than 1 second on a hard drive since the fastest consumer models max out at about 150MB/s. Your test results are probably down to Window's built in cache keeping the contents of the file in memory so that subsequent reads are faster.

> Loading too many files! If so, Why Microsoft didn't compact them in
>   one file?

Actually it kind of does. Windows 8 introduced a technology called Hybrid Boot which partially 'hibernates' the computer when you choose Shut Down. This can significantly improve startup times by reducing the number of files that need to be read at startup because it can restore the contents of the RAM from one big file. But unlike the hibernation it doesn't remember all the programs you have open.

In practice due to these improvments Windows 8 is supposed to start up quicker than Windows 7. You have said that your laptop is taking 50 seconds - this seems like quite a long time, especially for a reasonably recent Core i5 model.

There are many possible reasons for the slowness - e.g. it might be bogged down with bloatware/malware, you might have a corrupt Windows installation, or you might have faulty hardware. You need to give more information about what hardware and software setup you have and indicate how long each stage of the boot process is taking.

You could try manually defragmenting the hard drive, although it shouldn't normally be necessary. It might also be worth using a program with hard drive diagnostic capabilities, e.g. [SpeedFan](http://almico.com/speedfan.php) in order to check for problems.

You could try using the `msconfig.exe` tool to selectively disable startup processes and services, although you would have to be careful with this tool as it can mess up your system. If you really do have a fresh installation of Windows then you shouldn't need to do this as there should be very few startup items - perhaps you could post a screenshot.

Note that a lot of laptops now have hybrid HDD/SSD systems where a small SSD is used to hold the hibernation file and commonly used programs whilst the HDD is used for all other files. In practice this makes a big difference, e.g. my Lenovo only takes about 5-10 seconds to boot.